# How do I capture an optional delimited string and return it?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have:

```
"here is BN1234 and other BN456[these are things] and other".scan(/BN([a-zA-Z0-9\-_.]+)/)
=>[["1234"], ["456"]]
```

I'd like to add an optional fragment that can capture an optional bracket-delimited string following the result. The capture could contain any UTF-8 characters up to a terminating end bracket. Ideally:

```
"here is BN1234 and other BN456[these are things]".scan(???)
=>[["1234"], ["456[these are things]"]]
```

Googling this, I have tried:

```
"here is BN1234 and other BN456[these are other things]".scan(/BN([a-zA-Z0-9\-_.]+)([.+])?/)
=> [["1234", nil], ["456", nil]] # <- NO
```

and:

```
"here is BN1234 and other BN456[these are other things]".scan(/BN([a-zA-Z0-9\-_.]+\[\d+\])?/)
=> [[nil], [nil]]
```

What would be the optional pattern to get the desired result?

Comment: When working on regex, it's really useful to start with something like http://rubular.com.

Comment: thx for heads up on rubular - I was trying to remember it - but wasn't coming back in results - looking at the answers; I doubt I would gotten it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start with a site like Rubular, you'll find it a lot easier to create/debug your pattern.

This is a starting point: http://rubular.com/r/G93iPo0j5C

```
/BN([\w.-]+)(\[[^\]]+\])?/
```

Applying that to a `scan`:

```
'here is BN1234 and other BN456[these are things]'.scan(/BN([\w.-]+)(\[[^\]]+\])?/)
# => [["1234", nil], ["456", "[these are things]"]]
```

A little tweak to adjust the capture results in:

```
'here is BN1234 and other BN456[these are things]'.scan(/BN([\w.-]+(?:\[[^\]]+\])?)/)
# => [["1234"], ["456[these are things]"]]
```

Flattening the result to get rid of the embedded sub-arrays:

```
'here is BN1234 and other BN456[these are things]'.scan(/BN([\w.-]+(?:\[[^\]]+\])?)/).flatten
# => ["1234", "456[these are things]"]
```

When creating patterns, it's important to start simply, and to reduce the visual noise as much as possible. Instead of using `[a-zA-Z0-9\-_.]`, learn how character sets work. `\d` is equivalent to `[0-9]` so you can reduce the pattern to `[a-zA-Z\d\-_.]`.

Reducing further, `\w` is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` so the pattern becomes `[\w\-.]`.

Finally, `-` inside `[]` should be defined at the start or end of the set, because then it will be automatically escaped, further reducing visual noise: `[\w.-]`.

> can I ask what that internal [^] does?

Yes. You can ask. Let's break it down: You want to capture text inside square-brackets. To capture square brackets, you have to escape the leading one, and for clarity you should escape the trailing one. `\[[^\]]+\]` is:

- `\[` = the literal starting '`[`'.
- `[^\]]` = the set of characters *not* matching a literal '`]`'.
- `\]` = the closing literal '`]`' character.

There's something very important to learn, and remember, about regex patterns. They're very powerful, but they are *NOT* the answer to every computing/parsing problem that exists. Every programmer I've met, when they learned about regex, immediately tried to use them for everything they could. That isn't a good decision, because it's incredibly easy to write patterns that have holes in their logic that leak, usually quite badly. Failing to escape `.` or `[`, or misusing `*` or `+`, or running into greediness problems, can cause bugs that are really hard to find. Writing long patterns only increases the likelihood of opening those holes, so keep them short and sweet, test the heck out of them, then learn how to aggregate them to reuse little ones to create big ones.

An infamous character on Stack Exchange wrote "[Regular Expressions: Now You Have Two Problems](http://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/)", which is good reading. The book "[Perl Best Practices](http://search.oreilly.com/?q=perl%20best%20practices)" has a good chapter explaining how and why to use patterns and how to write them in a readable/maintainable fashion. There's also "[Mastering Regular Expressions](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596528126.do)" which is a must-have reference. You don't have to know everything about them, but having the "MRE" book will give you a good place to look when you have questions.

Comment: thx - can I ask what that internal `[^\]` does? I think everything else  kinda makes sense (although I don't think I would ever have gotten it).

Answer (score 1):

```
"here is BN1234 and other BN456[these are things] and other".scan(/BN([a-zA-Z0-9\-_.]+(?:\[[^\]]+\])?)/)
# =>  [["1234"], ["456[these are things]"]]
```

You can check it [here](http://rubular.com/r/HeQbywg1kt)

Answer (score 1):

I would use a slightly different regex than what others have suggested

```
str = "here is BN1234 and other BN456[these are other things]"

str.scan(/(?:^|\s)BN(\d+(?:\[[^\]]+\])?)/i)
  #=> [["1234"], ["456[these are other things]"]]
```

- `(?:...)` indicates a non-capture group.
- `(?:^|\s)` requires that `BN` be at the beginning of the string (`^`) or (`|`) be immediately preceded by a least one whitespace character (`\s`).
- `\d+` requires `BN` to be immediately followed by at least one digit.
- the `?` at the end of `(?:\[[^\]]+\])?` means the non-capture group `(?:\[[^\]]+\])`is optional.
- `\[` and `\]` are (literal) open and close braces.  Escaping is required to distinguish them from the beginning and ending of a regex group.
- `[^\]+` matches one or more characters in the character class `[^\]`.  `^\]` means all characters other than right brace are matched by the character class.